# US resident traveling from Mexico to other country than USA

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, mexico

If a US resident travels from Mexico to other countries with other passport which hasn't shown to US immigration will US immigration be able to track the resident flight history?

Comment: Many countries share immigration data with each other. It might well be possible for some destinations and not for others. If you could be more specific about which countries you're interested in then a more definitive answer might be possible. However, the nature of your query suggests that you won't want to do that.

Comment: Why do you care about whether the US knows where you're travelling? We don't help people break the law.

Comment: @DavidRicherby nobody said they were breaking the law. They could just be curious, or unhappy at the idea of the US getting their travel data from a privacy point of view.

Comment: @MarkMayo Sure. Though I would note that if I, as a non-US citizen, had serious privacy concerns around the activities of the US government, I probably wouldn't choose to be resident there. Also, don't you have to give details of all passports you hold when applying for a US visa or entering visa-free?

Answer (score 3):

Realistically nobody can answer that question.  Most people because they don't know the answer, and the people that do know the answer because they will not be allowed to share it!

The level of information sharing between countries is something that is not made public.  There are absolutely agreements between specific countries to share information - with probably the best known of these being the "[Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes)" alliance, but even then what information is shared under such an agreement, and how each country uses it, is unknown.

It is certainly very possible that travelling from Mexico to a third country using a non-US passport could be done without the US knowing - but it would most likely depend on the country and passport involved.